# How do i configure with a command from another frame after instancing in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make it so whenever i select a radiobutton it will .insert() a value inside of an empty entry that is declared in another class and instanced in the application class.

```
import tkinter as tk

class DataDisplay(tk.Frame):
    """ Provides the GUI, powered by the Tkinter module. """

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets(parent)

    def create_widgets(self, parent):
        print("Creating widgets... ")

        # Radio buttons frame
        radiobuttons = Radiobuttons(parent)
        radiobuttons.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.NE)

        # ID, calibration date, arrival date frame.
        data_entry_frame = tk.Frame(parent, borderwidth=3, relief='ridge')
        data_entry_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.NE)

        # Producer info frame
        product_info = ProductInfo(data_entry_frame)
        product_info.pack(side=tk.TOP)


class Radiobuttons(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # Setting border-width and border-type
        self.configure(borderwidth=3, relief='ridge')
        # Setting self.radio to be an integer for function use.
        self.radio = tk.IntVar()
        # Defining radio-buttons
        rb = tk.Radiobutton(self, text='Molybdenum-99', variable=self.radio, value=1, indicatoron=0,
                            width=15, overrelief='sunken',
                            command= lambda: DataDisplay.product_info.iso_half_life_value_label.insert(0, 'test'))
        rb.pack(anchor=tk.W)
        rb = tk.Radiobutton(self, text='Technetium-99M', variable=self.radio, value=2, indicatoron=0,
                            width=15, overrelief='sunken',
                            command=lambda: print('Radiobutton selected Technetium99M'))
        rb.pack(anchor=tk.W)

    def get(self):
        return self.radio.get()

class ProductInfo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text='Insert here: ')
        self.label.grid(column=0, row=5)
        self.iso_half_life_value_label = tk.Entry(self)
        self.iso_half_life_value_label.grid(column=1, row=5)


print('Finished creating widgets.')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = DataDisplay(root)
    root.title("DataDisplay")
    root.geometry('800x800')
    root.resizable(True, True)
    root.mainloop()
```

The error i'm getting with my current attempt: AttributeError: type object 'DataDisplay' has no attribute 'product_info'

Expected result is to have a custom value based on radiobutton selection inserted into the product_info label.

Comment: What about using a minimal example? That would make our life easier...

Comment: Because the last time i tried that somebody complained about the code being incomplete.  I'll try and remove some redundant parts.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco i've changed it. I removed about 240 lines. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is the case with any python object, you need a reference to the object in order to change it. The simplest solution is to pass a reference to your objects to the other objects that need them.

For example, if you pass the instance of `DataDisplay` to `Radiobuttons`, `Radiobuttons` can then access the attributes of `DataDisplay`. For example:

```
class DataDisplay(...):
    def create_widgets(...):
        ...
        radiobuttons = Radiobuttons(parent, data_display=self)
        ...

class Radiobuttons(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data_display):
        ...
        rb = tk.Radiobutton(..., command= lambda: data_display.product_info.iso_half_life_value_label.insert(0, 'test'))
        ...
```

The other part of the problem is that you're not saving `product_info` as an attribute of the object. You need to do that when you create it:

```
self.product_info = ProductInfo(...)
```

Comment: As always you are the one to rescue me! thanks a lot. I had it working by changing the frame into a global variable but i figured that should never be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by making product_info a global variable. Not sure if this is best practice however.